# Flooring options for rejuvenating office space

Tags: flooring, tile

## CONTEXT

1000 sq-feet of 30 y.o tiled office space in North Florida

[image]

[image]

I am reasonably handy (changed the steering tie-rods in the car 6 months ago) and interested in determining if it makes sense to self install

## QUESTIONS

We are evaluating replacing the flooring with artificial wood laminate, carpeting, or tiling for future renters.

1. How to evaluate to  what degree is the current tile cleanable / reusable?
2. Is it necessary to remove the tile in order to install carpeting or artificial wood laminate?  If yes, why?
3. If unnecessary to remove tile to install laminate, how should the tile be prepped (beyond normal cleaning)?

If you have experience with this decision making, please state this in your response.  Insightful experience: lessons-learned or pitfalls to avoid are appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: If it's commercial vinyl tile (solid) you hire a janitorial service that knows what it's doing (and has proper commercial equipment, mostly serious floor buffers) to strip & buff. It's "commercial" in part because you can abrade the surface back to clean material if needed, until you wear right through the tile. This may get closed as being decorating advice.

Comment: Get it tested to see if it is vinyl-asbestos tile. The testing is not expensive and if it is just vinyl, then you have more options.

Comment: What Jim said. If it's got asbestos in it, then your best option is to leave it where it is and lay something over it.